# lost application menu 10.04 after upgrade

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-netbook, appmenu

After upgrade of 10.04 netbook remix edition to kernel 2.6.32.35 generic I lost application menu and now I have a clean desktop without any icon and a top bar with those icons: show desktop, usual icon network, battery, mail, date and switch off.
I'm able to recover application menu pressing [alt]+F1, how i can fix it to the top bar or better show icons as was before?

Answer (score 1):

Since you say "fix it to the top bar" I can assume you have the top bar displayed.

Try:
Move the mouse cursor into the top bar and right click.
Select the "Add to Panel..." option
When the Add to Panel window appears, scroll down and select "Main Menu"
Click Add and then Close

You should now have the Ubuntu logo, Applications, Places, and System menus in the top bar.  You can also move them right and left or lock them, explore the right click options when hovering over the menu.

Note if you have too much in the top bar, some things may not get displayed because of a lack of real estate.